# HighCharts: Is this.percentage accessible in the tooltip formatter?

Tags: highcharts

Sample code:

```
formatToolTip: function() {
        var tt = this.x + ' = ' + this.y + ' (this.percentage + ' %)';
        return tt;
}
```

`this.percentage` is always undefined. I am a newbie working with highcharts 3.0.0

Comment: nned more info: what chart type? percentage is only calculate for pie charts.
Other chart types you will need to calculate the percentage yourself.

Comment: Thanks! This is a column chart. I guess the 'newbie' part is coming through, I'll read the API ref more carefully

Answer (score 1):

This is an old example of how you can use the formatter function to get the %.  It relies on knowing the max value of the data, but you can use the getExtremes() method to pull that from the chart.

http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/H3Q9h/5/

```
var pcnt = Highcharts.numberFormat((this.y / 415 * 100),0,'.');
```

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.getExtremes%28%29

replace the 415 in the equation with a variable set as the dataMax value of the getExtremes() method.